# Android Passing Data

Tags: android

I need some advice on an application I am writing for a android using eclipse. I am writing an application that adds 2 numbers and passes the data back to the first activity using an intent. I am not sure if I use intent.putExtra ( num1 +num 2), any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks-

Comment: u need to startActivityForResult and onActivityResult stuff. if u r not aware about this, let me know. i will try to explain it with example

Comment: It would be intent.putExtra("added_vals", num1+num2); if you wanted to do it that way. The thing is, though, that the activity is supposed to be adding the data itself. So somewhere in your activity you should do num1 + num2 = addedNumber and use intent.putExtra("added_val", addedNumber); or something.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose u r going from Activity A to Activity B and u want to return something back to Activity A, then here is an example. Hope it helps :

Code to go to Activity B o button click :

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

        @Override  
        public void onClick(View arg0) {  
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);  
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
            //2 is the request code. u can choose ur own.
        }  
    });
```

also in the same activity override onActivityResult method :

```
@Override  
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
   {  
             super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  

              // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
               if(requestCode==2)  
                     {  
                        Int x = data.getIntExtra ("num1");
                        Int y = data.getIntExtra ("num2");

                     }       
 }
```

And in your Activity B

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

            @Override  
            public void onClick(View arg0) {  
                Bundle b = new Bundle();  
                b.putIntExtra("num1", int1);
                b.putIntExtra("num2", int2);
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.put(b);
                finish();//finishing activity  
            }  
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this in your first activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            int result=data.getIntExtra("result");
        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}//onActivityResult
```

And this in your class that does the math:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",sumOfNumbers);
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start the Activity that adds the 2 numbers with startActivityForResult() and then implement the onActivityResult() callback to receive the result.

In the Activity that adds the 2 numbers you can set the result with setResult(resultCode, Intent):

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result", sum);
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

Check out the Android docs: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the onActivityResult function of the parent Activity class.

```
int RESULT_CODE_CHILD_ACTIVITY = 1;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode) 
    {
        case (RESULT_CODE_CHILD_ACTIVITY) : 
        {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
            {
                int yourInt = data.getIntExtra("yourInt", -1);
            }
            break;
        } 
    }
}
```

And you'll want to override the onDestroy function of your child activity to pass the data back.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
    int yourInt = 5 + 4;
    resultIntent.putExtra(yourInt, "yourInt");
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```